# Не могу придумать как можно двигаться по строчке и вытаскивать нужные данные

Tags: java

Не могу придумать как можно двигаться по строчке и вытаскивать нужные данные.

Строка в `text.txt`:

```
Name1:1,2,3.Name2:3,2,1.Name3:3,3,3.
```

Разделитель данных `.`
Не могу вытащить эти элементы (выделены жирным: Name1:**1**,2,3.Name2:**3**,2,1.Name3:**3**,3,3.)  с помощью цикла.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("text.txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String str;
            while ((str = read.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] str_1 = str.split(".");
                String temp = str_1[1];
                String num_1 = temp.split(",")[0];
            }

        }catch (Exception e){}

    }
}
```

Comment: После того, как разделили по `.`, разделите по `:`, останеться `1,2,3`, ну и в конце разделите по `,`. Либо используйте регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйся RegEx:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

В Java он должен быть, погугли.